# Ignore space or newline when reading a line

Tags: c, newline, whitespace, scanf

I'm reading a line till enter/return is pressed(like a terminal), but I have some problems when it comes to ignoring just space(s) and just enter(s).

This is how I read and check for space/new line/comment:

```
char line[256];
while(printf("%s>", shell_name) && scanf(" %50[^\n]", line) != EOF){
        if(isspace(*line) == 0 && line[0] != '#' && line[0] != '\n'){
```

Input example:

```
mysh>echo lol
lol
mysh> *spaces*
mysh>
mysh> *next line(enter)*
mysh>
```

Comment: You should add example input for which this snippet doesn't work. Include current and expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `" "` in `scanf(" %50[^\n]", line)` consumes all leading whites-space (including `'\n'`), not just leading spaces.

`isspace(*line) == 0` and `line[0] != '\n'` are always true.

Suggest `fgets()/sscanf()`.  User input is far easier to handle with *first* getting the line and *then* 2) parsing it.

```
char buf[256];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) HandleEOF();
char line[256];
if (sscanf(buf, " %50[^\n]", line) < 1) Handle_WhiteSpaceOnlyLine();
GoodToGo();
```